# TypeError: '(slice(None, 59, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan, algorithmic-trading

I am having the below table where I want to remove these rows with NaN values.

```
                   date    Open  ...  Real Lower Band  Real Upper Band
0   2020-07-08 08:05:00  2.1200  ...              NaN              NaN
1   2020-07-08 09:00:00  2.1400  ...              NaN              NaN
2   2020-07-08 09:30:00  2.1800  ...              NaN              NaN
3   2020-07-08 09:35:00  2.2000  ...              NaN              NaN
4   2020-07-08 09:40:00  2.1710  ...              NaN              NaN
5   2020-07-08 09:45:00  2.1550  ...              NaN              NaN
```

These `NaN` values are til row no. 58

For this, I wrote the following code. But the above error occurred.

```
data.drop(data[:59,:],inplace= True)
print(data)
```

Please help me!

Comment: And those NaN are in last 3 columns.

Comment: drop is by index not data also you could use dropna with threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to choose from:

1. Drop rows by index label.

   df.drop(list(range(59)), axis=0, inplace=True)
2. Drop if nans in selected columns.

   df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Real Upper Band'], inplace=True)
3. Select rows to keep by index label slice

   df = df.loc[59:, :] # 59 is the label in index, if index was date then replace 59 with corresponding datetime
4. Select rows to keep by integer index slice (similar to slicing a list)

   df = df.iloc[59:, :] # 59 is the 0-index row number, regardless of what index is set on df
5. Filter with .loc and boolean array returned by .isna()

   df = df.loc[~df['Real Upper Band'].isna(), :]

Remember that loc and iloc work with two dimensions when applied to dataframes, it is recomended to use full slice `:` to avoid ambiguity and improve performance according to the docs   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep rows from *59-th* on, so the shortest code you can run is:

```
data = data[59:]
```